# Configure VMware to use VPN

Tags: vpn, virtual-machines

I have a W10 machine running VMware. On VMWare I have a CentOS installation. Is it possible to configure the VM to use a VPN and my host machine just use my regular connection?

Thanks

Comment: `I have a W10 machine running VMware` - Wow! How you're able to run an entire company of that size on your Windows 10 machine is a mystery. Bravo, sir!

Comment: "Is it possible to configure the VM to use a VPN and my host machine just use my regular connection?" - @joeqwerty already addressed the fact that a 3 year member on SE can't figure out where to post a question, but the deeper issue here is this is a drive-by question.  No attempted solutions, no research.  :(

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Assuming that you mean an Installed Vmware Player / Workstation on the Windows 10 machine with network/ internet connectivity on it, there should be no problems in configuring the VPN client inside the guest machine. With such setup the host operating system would not know of it.

This way you can have a situation in which the guest machine has access to certain resources behind a VPN and the host machine would not, if that is what you're after.

Comment: You start with hyperbole, continue with generalizations, and finish with broad assumptions of the OP's configuration and setup.  Succinct answers should still be good answers.

Comment: I have edited my answer to better reflect the state of those who felt offended by the OP's question. I realize that the question was pretty vague and general, but I wanted to answer that anyway instead of flaming it, and with minimal level of detail in the question I could only do broad assumptions and generalizations.
As a new user I believe I also have the right to make mistakes, especially when trying to help someone.

Comment: My downvote was because we generally do not want to feed the trolls. Or those who abuse the intent of the site. Any answer would be a bad answer, even a good answer. =)

Comment: @bocian85 - agree with your comment.  I was bitter this morning when I commented.  Glad you are willing to take some ribbing. :)